# Frame Navigation in Wpf application

Tags: wpf

I have this application where there is a frame and I navigated the frame to a different Page where there are certain button which must be able to navigate the frame to another page but i don't know how to change the navigate property of the frame from another class somewhere. Can anyone help me out with that and also how do i change the text property of the page identifier from the another class.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this? On button click event handler.

```
framename.Navigate(new Page1());
```

where Page1 is a xaml file to which you need to navigate to.

EDIT : 
Your requirement could be easily implemented using MVVM model. The basic concept behind MVVM is that you can bind your data to properties in the view model class. So that you could easily control the properties of child classes from parent class and vice versa using instances of view model classes.

Could you try this for the time being?
    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).Framename.Navigate(new Page());

Also try this, to make the component as public.
For access controls in other WPF windows, you have to declare that control as a public, the default declaration of controls in WPF is public, and you can specify it with this code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

And after than you can search in all active windows in application to find than windows have that control like this:

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window.GetType() == typeof(Window1))
    {
       (window as Window1).textBox1.Text = "I change it from another windows";
    }
}
```

Comment: no i guess you didn't understand the question. the frame is in a different class and the controls are in different how do i share the controls?

Comment: I have updated, please check. My suggestion is to go for MVVM model.

Comment: If you got the point, please select my answer as the correct answer(Click on tick mark to make it green), so that it will be helpful to others too.